# Jaxb2Marshaller how it holds JAXBContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-jms, jaxb2

I use `MarshallingMessageConverter` as implementation of `MessageConverter` bean. I'm using `Jaxb2Marshaller` as an implementation of `org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller`class. I set classes to be bound in this way:

`marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[]{Class1.class,Class2.class})`

Also i can set classes by using `JAXBContext` class and retrieve Marshaller and Unmarashaller:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Class1.class,Class2.class)
jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
```

This is similar to `Jaxb2Marshaller` because it has internal field of `JAXBContext`. Creating new JAXBContext for every parse request is very expensive.

My question is: If i declare `Marshaller` by using `Jaxb2Marshaller` all classes  to be bind in this call `marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[]{Class1.class,Class2.class})` will be reused in each parse request and will be thread safe, or `JAXBContext` from this classes will be created again for each request? I use this `Jaxb2Marshaller` as `Bean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the JAXB spec-- JAXBContext is thread safe. Marshaller and Unmarshaller are not and should be created once-per use, or wrapped with some sort of thread-safe service to synchronize access to the marshaller and unmarshaller.

Comment: And to answer the OP question; Spring uses a single context - either during initialization or on first use (controlled by `lazyInit`) and creates a new marshaller from the context for each use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer)